# 'Most' correct format for gherkin on a RESTful API

Tags: java, junit, gherkin

I am currently writing a java API that has an endpoint upon which I want to be able to perform POST, PATCH, GET and DELETE actions.

Here's the sample JSON for a POST

```
{
    "type": "suppliers",
    "name":"Toilet Duck Network Energy LTD"
}
```

And here's the response from the API which I'm formatting to correspond to the [JSON-API format](http://jsonapi.org/format/#document-meta):

```
{
    "status": "SUCCESS",
    "jsonapi": {
        "version": "1.0"
    },
    "data": {
        "type": "suppliers",
        "name": "Toilet Duck Network Energy LTD"
    }
}
```

I already have the endpoint up and running and I have my gherkin stories and step definitions done. Here's a sample of the gherkin

```
Background:
    Given the system knows about the following Suppliers:
        | supplierid | suppliername                 |
        | 1          | Blue Network Energy LTD      |
        | 2          | Red Network Energy LTD       |
        | 3          | Orange Network Energy LTD    |
        | 4          | Green Network Energy LTD     |
        | 5          | Yellow Network Energy LTD    |
        | 6          | Violet Network Energy LTD    |

Scenario Outline: SUPPLIER: GET RESOURCE - SUCCESS
    And the client executes a GET request for <supplierid>
    Then the response status is: <status>
    And the response has the jsonapi version
    And the response has the Supplier: <supplier>

        Examples:
        |supplierid | supplier                      | status    |
        | 1         | "Blue Network Energy LTD"     | "SUCCESS" |
        | 2         | "Red Network Energy LTD"      | "SUCCESS" |
        | 3         | "Orange Network Energy LTD"   | "SUCCESS" |
        | 4         | "Green Network Energy LTD"    | "SUCCESS" |
        | 5         | "Yellow Network Energy LTD"   | "SUCCESS" |
        | 6         | "Violet Network Energy LTD"   | "SUCCESS" |
```

And here's the step definition for `Then the response status is: <status>`. Note that it allows for calculating the status for a response from a POST, PATCH, GET (collection or resource), or DELETE. Lots of reusability.

```
@Then("^the response status is: \"([^\"]*)\"$")
public void the_response_status_is(String arg1) throws Throwable {

    String collectionResponseStatus = "";
    String resourceResponseStatus = "";

    if (this.resourceResponseTest != null){

        resourceResponseStatus = this.resourceResponseTest.getStatus().toString();
        Assert.assertTrue(resourceResponseStatus.equals(arg1.toString()));
    }

    if (this.collectionResponseTest != null){

        collectionResponseStatus = this.collectionResponseTest.getStatus().toString();
        Assert.assertTrue(collectionResponseStatus.equals(arg1));
    }

}
```

I've been wanting to format the Gherkin to allow for a little more re-use, but I've found that there's other ways of writing the Gherkin which would mean I would need to move testing of certain parts of the content elsewhere

[This article](http://gregbee.ch/blog/effective-api-testing-with-cucumber) recommends I do something like this:

```
Given the system knows about the following suppliers:
            | supplier                          |
            | "Blue Network Energy LTD"         |
            | "Red Network Energy LTD"          |
When the client requests a list of suppliers
Then the response is a list containing "2" suppliers
And one supplier has the attributes:
        | id | supplier                         | type      |
        | 2  | "Red Network Energy LTD"         | suppliers |
And one supplier has the attributes:
        | id | supplier                         | type      |
        | 2  | "Red Network Energy LTD"         | suppliers |
```

But this doesn't leave any room for checking the following:

- content-Type Header
- HTTP status code
- and other things I haven't yet encountered

Should these items, not of interest to the user, be checked with unit tests rather than feature files?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a different approach, see if it can be useful for you:

`And` validate response as "Id=2,Supplier=Red Network Energy LTD,type=suppliers, Content Type=text/html, Status Code=404, Status=Success"

```
public class StepDefinitions{

@When("^validate response as \"([^\"]*)\"$");
public void validateResponse(String input){
 String[] inputs = input.split(",");
 HashMap<String, String> fields = new HashMap<String,String>();
 for(String ip : inputs){
   fields.put(ip.split("=")[0],ip.split("=")[1]);
 }

 for(String field : fields.keySet()){
  String fieldValue = fields.get(field);
  //You have both field name and field value here
  switch(field.trim().toUpperCase()){
    case "ID":
         //your code here to validate id
         break;
     case "SUPPLIER":
         //your code here to validate id
         break;
    //Other cases here
  }
 }
}
```